# ffmpeg overlay live video streams and live stream the output

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

I've got two live streams running on Wowza Cloud, both with video and one also contains audio.
I want to overlay one of the video feeds as a picture in picture video and then stream the "merged" streams back again to another streaming endpoint.

I have tested but have so far not found a way to achieve this. It should keep running until the streams are done.

Here is what i've gathered so far from different forums:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i RTSP_INPUT_1 -stream_loop -1 -i RTSP_INPUT_2 -filter_complex "overlay=70:70" -flvflags no_duration_filesize -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -f flv RTMP_OUTPUT
```

I added the -stream_loop -1 because it seemed to be working (I at least got some incoming bits on the output stream) but the ffmpeg function stopped executing. But even with the loop it still finished and doesn't run endlessly until there is no more input.

I can't seem to crack how I can get ffmpeg to keep overlaying the streams and sending the output to a new stream without stopping.